# Which level would be appropriate for this homebrew Mass Dimensional Anchor?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, balance

Since *dimensional anchor* is sometimes used as a protection from teleport-esque spell, I am going to devise this mass version of spell. My initial thoughts are presented here:

> ### Dimensional Anchor, Mass
>
> *Abjuration*
>
> - Components: V, S
> - Casting time: 1 standard action
> - Range: Long (400 ft. + 40 ft. per level)
> - Target: Creatures within 20-foot-radius sphere centered at a point within range
> - Duration: 1 min. / level
> - Saving throw: Reflex negates; see below
> - Spell Resistance: Yes (object)
>
> Targets fall under the effect of successful *dimensional anchor*. Willing targets may voluntarily fail the saving throw. Any unattended objects are automatically affected.

My question is, which spell level would be appropriate for this spell? I initially thought 8th (*Dimensional lock* 4 + Usual *mass* addition of 4), but will it be appropriate, or inappropriate for this spell level, and what would be the reason?

Comment: Do you have a reason why you think the common +4 would be inappropriate in this case? Since you initially thought that, what changed your mind? Being able to address those issues directly will help make the answers more focused.

Comment: Is there a reason that you made it require a save?  Neither of the existing similar effects (dimensional anchor and dimensional lock) allow a save.  Also, is there a reason that you'd rather use this than dimensional lock?

Comment: Reflex save was selected just because I thought it makes no sense to convert an attack roll spell to a spell with no refusal. *Dimensional lock* targets an area, not persons, and that is the reason why I thought about this homebrew.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow the pattern with anticipate teleportation, and anticipate teleportation greater as they deal with the category of "teleportation protection" and are the same levels. Anticipate teleportation is level 4, and Anticipate Teleportation, Greater is level 6.

For you, Dimensional Anchor is ranged touch, no save. Turn that into a reflex negates is ... a significant nerf. The extra range is negligible at these levels. Therefore, turning this into an AoE for a +2 penalty is one level better than Chain spell, (a +3 penalty) which is appropriate considering the greatly decreased utility of your version.

Answer (score -3):

If you have access to the 3.0 Epic Level Handbook, you can use that to get an idea of the expected change in spell level from changing area of effect, duration, range etc using the rules for creating epic spells.

Start with the assumption that you could make dimensional anchor at level 4, and then increase the spellcraft DC by 8 (or maybe 9-10 to reflect increasing int) to get to a level 8 spell

Comment: -1: The rules for epic spellcasting are really not very well written in general, and they don't translate back into the regular spellcasting system at all.

Comment: Even if the standard spell "fits well" with the epic spellcasting rules, the question's intension was (if converted into epic rules, that is) "what would be the DC difference of this modification" rather than "which enhancements are appropriate for this DC difference".

Comment: Arle, that mwas my point. We know what the modifications we want are, and thus can calculate the spell DC difference. The spell level difference (what we want) is then just half the DC difference or thereabouts.